# Modify text displayed in thumnail of asset library- O365

Tags: branding

I have a client with a large Asset Library of car images. The current thumbnail shows the name of the file as well as the image specifics (jpg, size, etc.). The client instead wants the thumbnail to display the name of the car (pulled from Car Name Field), Manufacturer (pulled from Manufacturer Field) and finally the image details (JPG, size, etc..).

Can someone point me to some code I can use to accomplish this? I am an architect not a developer but should be able to figure out some jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Client side rendering like JSLink to present the item in the way you want. Edit the page and Edit the webpart. go to "Miscellaneous" options of the webpart. Find JS Link in the botton part. This is a method to attach javascript JS files to override the rendering of items. You may need to write java script code separately and upload to site assets or master pages library.

Learn more about JS Links from below links

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
http://msftplayground.com/2014/08/custom-list-view-by-using-the-js-link-property/